# mysql Left,right join not return null values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join, right-join

**sql code:**

```
SELECT * from propertyfield as pf 
RIGHT JOIN property as p 
ON (pf.pfid = p.propID)
```

not return null values

**or**

```
SELECT * from propertyfield as pf 
RIGHT JOIN property as p 
ON (pf.pfid = p.propID) 
where p.propID is null
```

not return null values

Comment: improve the quality of this question. its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: so your question is  .. ?

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking how to make them not return null values, or is the problem that they aren't returning null values when they should?

Comment: Add more information about table and column data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT * from propertyfield as pf 
LEFT JOIN property as p 
ON (pf.pfid = p.propID)
```

From your question, It says that `p.propID` has null values. So let the `propertyfield` be your left tabe, which gives all data from it. and `property` be your right table, which gives the corresponding values or null if no values.

Comment: SELECT * from propertyfield as pf 
LEFT JOIN property as p 
ON (pf.pfid = p.propID) where (estateID = 22) or estateID is null 
working now..thank you

Comment: @RamazanApaydın : If you find the answer useful, accept it, it will help others with same issue.